# Create multiple records in the same access table from one entry

Tags: ms-access

I am building a payroll prep solution for multiple stores and about 100 employees. There is some fairly complex math involved with multiple bonus and hours calculations.  I built out a working model in excel, but it seems like Access is a much better solution due to the sheer amount of records and complexity of processing that has to happen.  I haven't done a lot in access.

I basically need to build a data entry form that the user can enter multiple types of hours into quickly and then is processed as separate records (1 for regular, OT, DT etc...) using the same employee information.  Each pay type has different GL Codes etc... the output is a report that HR can use to verify and enter proper hours.  I am currently carrying all hours records in one table with a field for each pay type and employee information.  I'm interested in whether this makes sense versus a separate table for each hours type; or if I carry it in one table, what the best way to process the data I capture is (I need to produce something that shows each employee, pay type etc in summary form.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you the traditional way to do it would be to keep the pay types in a separate table.

However, if the pay types are relatively stable and/or small in number there's no reason you can't keep them in one row.  So you could have a report like:

```
SELECT "1" AS PayType, Sum(Payroll.Pay1) AS Hours
FROM Payroll
UNION
SELECT "OT" AS PayType, Sum(Payroll.PayOT) AS Hours
FROM Payroll
UNION
SELECT "DT" AS PayType, Sum(Payroll.PayDT) AS Hours
FROM Payroll
```

I would generally use the first method, in which case you'd have a table with the pay type and GL, a table with employees, and a many-to-many table with EmployeeID, PayTypeID and Hours.  This gives you the most flexibility in case you need to add or remove pay types, or create new report layouts.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.